# JSLint: Unexpected dangling in a constructor function. Why?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have a constructor function:

```
function Constructor(parameter) {
    this._property = parameter;
}
```

and later

```
Constructor.prototype.someFunction = function() {...}
```

JSLint is complaining

*Unexpected dangling '_' in '_property'*

But when I read the explanation to this warning I find this :

> ESLint only raises this warning for variable and function identifiers and not for object property identifiers. [jslinterrors.com](http://jslinterrors.com/unexpected-dangling-_-in-a/)

I thought `this._property` would be an object property... so I would expect that JSLint should be happy with that. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It seems the confusion comes because you think object properties are not identifiers. In fact they are identifiernames, a superset of identifiers. But if they begin or end with `_` they will also be identifiers.

Comment: Well I think that both are identifiers, but that they are treated different depending on the kind of variable that they are pointing to. I thought in this case a variable identifier is the name of a local variable and an object property identifier is  a name of a variable that is part of a prototype or object.

Comment: Is this a **J**SLint question or an **E**SLint one? You have a jslint tag and mention that JSLint is complaining, but then cite an **E**SLint-specific bit of text from jslinterrors.com. If you want ESLint behavior, I know a good solution... ;^)

Comment: I believed that JSLint would also use ESLint... but if that is wrong this is the explanation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

js doesn't have notion of"private" & identifiers prefixed with the underscore character are often used to indicate a private variable but here it does not provide any privacy

If you're using `JSLint`, you can fix the error by setting the `nomen` (nomenclature) option to `true`.

```
/*jslint nomen: true */
function Constructor(parameter) {
    this._property = parameter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see for yourself by logging your Constructor that `this` isn't added to the front of methods/variables:

[JSBIN of the code below](https://jsbin.com/dobira/2/edit?js,console)

```
function Constructor(parameter) {
  this._property = parameter;
  this.property = parameter;
}

var x = new Constructor(5);
console.log(x); 
// logs: 
{
  _property: 5, // dangling error
  property: 5
}
```

You can follow directions to turn off notification of the error [HERE](https://jslinterrors.com/unexpected-dangling-_-in-a)

or not use an underscore.